# TypeScript protected property not visible in union

Tags: typescript, this, union-types

I have the following TypeScript snippet:

```
class A {
  protected x: any;
}

class B {
  protected x: any;
}

const fn1 = function(this: A) {
  return this.x; // works
};

const fn2 = function(this: A|B) {
  return this.x; // error: 'x' does not exist on A|B
};
```

In `fn2`, `this` is typed as `A|B`. Both `A` and `B` have the same property `x` (with the same visibility). Why can't I reach `this.x` in `fn2`?

Comment: Nice question.  I think [microsoft/TypeScript#9974](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9974) and [microsoft/TypeScript#29132](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29132) are relevant, for anyone who gets around to answering this before I can.

Comment: Interesting. If I try `interface C extends A, B {}` I get `Interface 'C' cannot simultaneously extend types 'A' and 'B'.  Named property 'x' of types 'A' and 'B' are not identical.` It's a hint that `protected` makes the compiler think they are disparate even though the names/types match. Seems like a bug?

Comment: You can't access properties, whose visibility level declared as protected, outside of methods in top-level class or in inherited class. Thus, both cases should throw an error.

Comment: `fn1` works fine; `this` is typed to the class where the property lives. When it runs e.g. `fn1.bind(new A())()` or `A.prototype.fn1 = fn1; (new A()).fn1();` it is effectively part of the `A` class and will run fine.

Comment: Then, why code like this ```const inst = new A(); inst.x;``` doesn't work? :)

Comment: Because `x` is marked `protected` in `A`. I think you are misunderstanding the use of the `this: A` cast inside the functions. Try it in plain JS: `A.prototype.fn = function() { return this.x; }; const a = new A(); console.log(a.fn());`